# Leaflet Group Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that have several layers LayerGroup and layerControl as the picture below. 
[image: Original]

I am wondering how can I still control those layers but the controller does not stay on the map but outside of the map such as 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create simple event listeners for the HTML elements outside the map, so they toggle the Leaflet layers inside.

e.g. something like:

```
 <label><input type='checkbox' id='bicycles-ctrl' value='1'>Bicycles</label>
```

```
 // Init the map and its layers as needed
 var map = L.map(...);
 var bicyclesLayer = L.geoJson(...);


 // Let's attach a DOM event handler, the Leaflet way:
 L.domEvent.on(

      // Whenever the 'bicycles-ctrl' DOM element...
      document.getElementById('bicycles-ctrl')),

      // ...dispatches a 'change' event...
      'change',

      // ...run this function
      function(ev) {
          // The 'target' property of the DOM event points to the instance 
          // of HTMLInputElement which dispatched the event
          var input = ev.target;

          // The 'value' property will be empty (falsy) if the checkbox is unchecked,
          // or will have the contents of the 'value' HTML attribute (truthy)
          // otherwise.
          if (input.value) {
               // If the checkbox is checked, display the leaflet layer
               bicyclesLayer.addTo(map);
          } else {
               // If not, hide the leaflet layer
               bicyclesLayer.remove();
          }
      }
 );
```

The specific event handlers will depend on your HTML markup and the behaviour you want to achieve.